# Checkbox select All not working in my case

Tags: jquery

I am trying to check all unchecked boxes at once but it's not working in my case. I have tried without table it works but with table it's not working even I am selecting with class but no success.

```js
$('#checkall').change(function() {
  $('.trcheck').prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-header with-border">
  <label class="btn btn-default" id="checkall">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkall"> Check All
  </label>
</div>
<div class="box-body">
  <table id="checkboxTable" class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Table name</th>
        <th>Gen form</th>
        <th>Gen code</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="trcheck">
        <td>{{$table->Tables_in_coder}}</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="chek"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="chek"></td>
        <td>
          <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="submit" id="genform">
          </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of issues with your code. Firstly you've repeated the same `id` on two elements when it must be unique. You put `checkall` on the `label` and the top-level checkbox. It should only be on the checkbox. This also prevented the `checked` property being read properly.

Secondly, you were trying to set the checked property on `.trcheck` which is a `tr` element. You need to call that on the child checkboxes, so change the selector to `.trcheck :checkbox`. Try this:

```js
$('#checkall').change(function() {
  $('.trcheck :checkbox').prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-header with-border">
  <label class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkall"> Check All
  </label>
</div>

<div class="box-body">
  <table id="checkboxTable" class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Table name</th>
        <th>Gen form</th>
        <th>Gen code</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="trcheck">
        <td>{{$table->Tables_in_coder}}</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="chek"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="chek"></td>
        <td>
          <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="submit" id="genform">
          </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of you have 2 elements with the id ``, fix this by changing the label `id="checkall"` to `for="checkall"`

Second change `$('.trcheck')` to `$('.trcheck input[type=checkbox]')` since your `.trcheck` is not an input

```js
$('#checkall').change(function() {
  $('.trcheck input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-header with-border">
  <label class="btn btn-default" for="checkall">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkall"> Check All
        </label>
</div>
<!-- /.box-header -->
<div class="box-body">
  <table id="checkboxTable" class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Table name</th>
        <th>Gen form</th>
        <th>Gen code</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
      </tr>

      <tr class="trcheck">
        <td>{{$table->Tables_in_coder}}</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="chek"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="chek"></td>
        <td>
          <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="submit" id="genform">
          </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```